# Get the torrent download directory from a torrent file using python-libtorrent

Tags: python, libtorrent, torrent

I need the default directory a torrent file will create when it is started using any torrent manager - as a string. I'm not a programmer, but with other help I was able to obtain the contents (files) of the torrent as strings:

```
info = libtorrent.torrent_info(torrent_file)
    for f in info.files():
      file_name = "%s" % (f.path)
      # do something with file_name
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the default directory"?  The directory in which the torrent's contents are downloaded depends entirely upon the Bittorrent client used.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but isn't it set in the torrent itself? I mean the default directory the torrent contents will be saved in under for example your downloads directory. Or the display name of the torrent while downloading. I got that impression from looking at the "complexity" of the download directory when it comes to the details included, which is still for example different from the main file or the directories in the torrent. I'm using rTorrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that there are two *kinds* of torrent files. Single-file torrents and multi-file torrents. The typical filename structure of the two kinds are:

single-file torrents: *save-path*/*torrent-name*

multi-file torrents: *save-path*/*torrent-name*/*all-files-in-torrent*

It sounds like you're looking for the name of the directory files of the torrent are stored in (by convention of most clients). i.e. the torrent *name*.

Example code to do this in python using libtorrent:

```
import libtorrent as lt
import sys

ti = lt.torrent_info(sys.argv[1])
if ti.num_files() > 1:
    print(ti.name())
else:
    # single-file torrent, name() may be a filename
    # instead of directory name
```